# What data, specifically can one obtain with Instagram's Basic Permissions access?

Tags: ios, instagram-api

Specifically our app needs to obtain and refresh users' follower and following (count only) figures on an hourly basis. Does anyone know, or is there any official resource which explains precisely what data can be obtained with Instagram's Basic Permissions access? Respective rate limits is a bonus!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

with `basic` permission, you can get just your Instagram profile info and posts. (i.e. the authenticated user's profile and posts)

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

API limit for these APIs is 5000/hour

You cannot get just anyone's profile info or posts. For this you need `public_content` permission.

Comment: thanks @krisrak But just to clarify:

Some background - We are an analytics app for users to connect and receive various stats and trends about their accounts, and we already have the basic permission.

We want users to connect their instagram accounts in order for our app to collect their follower and following count, and present them with data, graphs etc. 

So the Basic permission will not suffice for this task and we need to apply for the public_content permission?

Comment: If you just want the logged in user's follower/following count, then you just need `basic`

Comment: Thanks @krisrak and we can refresh this number on an hourly basis in order to update the users analytics? Sorry to quiz your on this, but I cant find this specific info elsewhere!

Comment: fir this API in documentastion `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`, there is no requirements, which means `basic` is good, if not there will be requirements for other APIs